# Python vlookup between list of dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, vlookup

I want to do a vlookup between two list of dictionary, but I don´t want to use Pandas, I would like to use pure python or some another light library.

So I have the first one list:

```
dict_1 = [{'Name': 'Grant', 'Number': 1111, 'Adress': 'Sal'},
          {'Name': 'Jhon', 'Number': 2222, 'Adress': 'Sal_3'}]
```

And then I have the second one:

```
dict_2 = [{'Name': 'Grant', 'High': 3333, 'Tell': 'None1'},
          {'Name': 'Jhon', 'High': 4444, 'Tell': 'None2'}]
```

And I want as a result a new list of dictionary where the main key is 'Name' between the two lists. The result should be something like:

```
[{'Name': 'Grant',
  'Number': 1111,
  'Adress': 'Sal',
  'High': 3333,
  'Tell': 'None1'},
 {'Name': 'Jhon',
  'Number': 2222,
  'Adress': 'Sal_3',
  'High': 4444,
  'Tell': 'None2'}]
```

Comment: Could you tell what would happen if one list has multiple dicts whe same Name ? Or maybe that won't happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product()` to obtain the Cartesian product between the two lists, then retain only the dictionaries which match on the `'Name'` key:

```py
from itertools import product

dict_1 = [{'Name': 'Grant', 'Number': 1111, 'Adress': 'Sal'},
          {'Name': 'Jhon', 'Number': 2222, 'Adress': 'Sal_3'}]
dict_2 = [{'Name': 'Grant', 'High': 3333, 'Tell': 'None1'},
{'Name': 'Jhon', 'High': 4444, 'Tell': 'None2'}]

result = [{**a, **b} for a, b in product(dict_1, dict_2) if a['Name'] == b['Name']]
print(result)
```

This prints:

```py
[{'Name': 'Grant', 'Number': 1111, 'Adress': 'Sal', 'High': 3333, 'Tell': 'None1'},
 {'Name': 'Jhon', 'Number': 2222, 'Adress': 'Sal_3', 'High': 4444, 'Tell': 'None2'}]
```

Comment: That is very inefficient, n² complexity is a very bad idea. Imagine 2 lists of 1000 items, instead of 2000 iterations, it would 1M to us only 2000, so 0.2% usefull

Comment: You're going to need to somehow differentiate between dictionaries in the first list and dictionaries in the second list. For example, what happens if you have two dictionaries that contain the same name in one of the lists? My solution handles that fine, whereas a one-pass approach would create one large dictionary for that name, which probably isn't desirable. Correctness without efficiency is preferable to efficiency without correctness.

Answer (score 3):

You need a main `dict` to group by the `Name`, then update the value to merge all dict, finally keep only the values of it (the merged dict)

```
result = {}
for value in dict_1 + dict_2:
    result.setdefault(value['Name'], {}).update(value)
result = list(result.values())
```

```
# after loop
{'Grant': {'Name': 'Grant', 'Number': 1111, 'Adress': 'Sal', 'High': 3333, 'Tell': 'None1'}, 
 'Jhon': {'Name': 'Jhon', 'Number': 2222, 'Adress': 'Sal_3', 'High': 4444, 'Tell': 'None2'}}

# final result
[{'Name': 'Grant', 'Number': 1111, 'Adress': 'Sal', 'High': 3333, 'Tell': 'None1'}, 
 {'Name': 'Jhon', 'Number': 2222, 'Adress': 'Sal_3', 'High': 4444, 'Tell': 'None2'}]
```